# nodejs-cassandra wont insert ints

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-cli

Ive tried a lot of things to get this fixed but it always seems to result in one or the other error.

Below is my code that i am using to execute the INSERT query.

```
            req.client.execute("INSERT INTO users (id,username,email,password,userFolder) VALUES (now(),'"+newUser.username+"','"+newUser.email+"','"+newUser.password+"',"+newUser.userFolder+");",function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message)
            }else{
                console.log("New user created")
            }
        });
```

The newUser.userFolder is simply defined in an array as `new Date().getTime()`

ive tried doing `parseInt(userFolder: new Date().getTime());` but it always seems to result in either this error

Also if you try `Number(userFolder :new Data().getTime());` it also does not work and results in the second error below;

Another thing i tried was simply typing `newUser.userFolder.valueOf()` which also results in the second error.

```
Invalid STRING constant (1443827057269) for "userfolder" of type int
```

or

```
Unable to make int from '1443827264655'
```

I have a feeling because the ' is before the number is causing this. However im not sure how to remove this.

I tried directly typing the number without using the array and it works fine, so the variable must be causing this issue.

Im basically moving from MySQL to cassandra and have a deadline for this project so any help would be appreciated.

By the way im using datastax driver for node-js

Answer (score 2):

```
req.client.execute("INSERT INTO users (id,username,email,password,userFolder) VALUES (now(), :username, :email, :userFolder)", 
                   newUser, 
                   {prepare: true }, 
                   function(err,result) {
                       if(err){
                           console.log(err.message)
                       }else{
                           console.log("New user created")
                   }
    });
```

Now a bit of details:

1. instead of creating a CQL string by concatenating values, the code above creates a parameterized query
2. the parameters in the query are retrieved by name (for example `username`) from the `newUser` object. The names of the parameters must be exactly the same as those of the properties in the object.

   There is an option to use `?` instead for positional parameters and then you can pass their values in an array:

   ```
   req.client.execute("INSERT INTO users (id,username,email,password,userFolder) VALUES (now(), ?, ?, ?)", 
              [newUser.username, newUser.password, newUser.userFolder], ...
   ```
3. `{prepare: true}` tells the client to prepare this statement so if it used multiple times it optimized both its execution and the transfer of the parameters

Last but not least, please do not store the password in clear.